# Common drive for Ubuntu 32 bit and 64 bit

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have searched askubuntu before writing this but was confused.
I have a hard disk which is having 320GB of space
Now I partitioned it like
78 GB for 32 bit Ubuntu
78 GB for 64 bit Ubuntu
160 GB for common space (I created as '/home' mount)
2 GB x 2 for each OS swap area

Now I have installed 32 bit in one 78 GB partition
But can not see other disk space.
I wanted to have that 160 GB space to share docs and other files

I didn't install 64 bit OS yet. Can anyone suggest me if I install 64 bit Ubuntu in the free 78 GB, will I get that configuration ?
My `df -a` gives this result :

[image]

and the `blkid` gives :

[image]

So will that do my purpose or I have to do something else? If something else then please explain what should I do.

`fdiak` gave this output:

[image]

Comment: yes, It has reasons

Comment: as can be seen from `fdisk` you have two big partitions sda1 and sda2. You have only 4gb extended partition and two 2Gb swaps in it. Most likely you have the rest part of the disk as unallocated space. You will probably find useful to observe all of it and manipulate in graphical interface, such as provided by `gparted`, could you please include such a screen shot from there?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the question describes not what have been created: there two partitions have been partitioned: sda1 (about 70Gb) and sda2 (about 150 Gb). All created partitions are shown by `df` independently on what OS(es) are installed.

You can also check what your system with:

- `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

[image]

- `sudo parted /dev/sda`

[image]

For example, in parted you should see a size for whole `/dev/sda` and `free space` for unallocated space.

Comment: Check this screen-shot : http://imgur.com/Bs3rxuN

Comment: I have edited your question added your screen shot to your questionr. As I commented there, "as can be seen from `fdisk` you have two big partitions sda1 and sda2. You have only 4gb extended partition and two 2Gb swaps in it. Most likely you have the rest part of the disk as unallocated space. You will probably find useful to observe all of it and manipulate in graphical interface, such as provided by `gparted`, could you please include such a screen shot from there?"